# Missing class properties transform in webpack/babel

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-server

i'm adding server side rendering on my app so i divided my webpack into three webpack config files,before dividing everything is working fine.
**webpack.base.js**

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const CSSExtract = new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css');
module.exports ={
    module:{
        rules: [{
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            options:{
                presets:[
                    'react',
                    'stage-0',
                    ['env',{targets:{browsers:['last 2 versions']}}]
                ]
            }
        },
            {
                test: /\.s?css$/,
                use: CSSExtract.extract({
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: true
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'sass-loader',
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: true
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                })
            },{
                test: /\.(gif|svg|jpg|png|ttf|eot|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/,
                loader: "file-loader",
            }
        ]
    },
    devtool:'inline-source-map',
    plugins: [
        CSSExtract
    ]
}
```

**webpack.client.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const baseConfig = require('./webpack.base.js');
const config = {
    entry: './src/client/app.js',
    output:{
        filename:'bundle.js',
        path:path.resolve(__dirname,'public')
    },

}
module.exports  = merge(baseConfig,config)
```

**webpack.server.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const baseConfig = require('./webpack.base.js');
const webpackNodeExternal = require('webpack-node-externals')

const config = {
    target:'node',
    entry: './src/index.js',

    output:{
        filename:'bundle.js',
        path:path.resolve(__dirname,'build')
    },
    externals:[webpackNodeExternal()]
}

module.exports  = merge(baseConfig,config)
```

**package.json(dependencies)**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.2",
    "babel-cli": "6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.5.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2017": "6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "webpack": "3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.5.1",
    "webpack-node-externals": "1.6.0",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0"
  }
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": [
        "es2015", "stage-0",
        "env",
        "react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-class-properties",
        "transform-object-rest-spread"
    ]
}
```

**scripts(package.json)**

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm-run-all --parallel dev:*",
    "dev:server": "nodemon --watch build  --exec \"node build/bundle.js\"",
    "dev:build-server": "webpack --config webpack.server.js --watch ",
    "dev:build-client": "webpack --config webpack.client.js --watch"
  }
```

it showing me **Module build failed: SyntaxError: Missing class properties transform.**

my problem is why my .babelrc file **presets** and **plugins** is not adding in webpack is there any other way to add **babel plugin** in webpack.
im using webpack 3.1.0

im stuck please help........

Comment: you need to upgrade to babel 7 since stage 0 and 2 are legacy

Comment: @SakhiMansoor i checked with es2017 also but same prblm,can u plz check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52167010/font-face-not-loading-from-ant-package-in-webpack?noredirect=1#comment91283877_52167010)

Comment: wait let me give you upgraded config.

Comment: this same code was working with my old [webpack](https://gist.github.com/theZulqarnain/f65d113b59be69660011c4121e7c0551)  file

Comment: there's an issue with your babelrc, order of presets

Comment: what is the right order...?

Answer (score 2):

### Please change the order of presets accordingly:

```
presets: ["es2015", "env", "react", "stage-0"]
```

for @font-face please add `url-loader`

```
{ test: /.(png|woff(2)?|eot|ttf|svg)(?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }
```

Let me know if the issue still persists

Comment: right now problem is `@font-face {` not accepting by webpack/babel as i sent that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52167010/font-face-not-loading-from-ant-package-in-webpack?noredirect=1#comment91283877_52167010)

Comment: I think you need to add url loader for fonts. I have edited my answer.

Comment: bro i already tried,again your code also but same prblm(url-loader also installed)

Comment: what error you're getting ? missing class properties transform ?

Comment: `SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` => `@font-face {`

Comment: If you share it over github then it would be easier to find the bug

Comment: can u check twitter ac or yahoo mail ):